# Where To Test Python Code

Tags: python, terminal, ide

I get slightly nervous posting in here because these are not my waters yet. Please bear with, I am very new to the world of code. I do my best to find answers to questions before I ask them; time is very valuable so I appreciate yours.

When I run code under Python in Terminal do I run the risk of damaging my system if I run bad code? My guess is no but I'd rather ask than regret. To follow up that question is there an editor that includes a built in interpreter so that I can write code and see it interpreted in the same window? Or is the best practice to write in an editor and run it in Terminal? Since syntax highlighting isn't available in Terminal I'm assuming that writing in Terminal is less than efficient.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Are you asking about the convenience of running code interactively, or the security of running code that might damage your system?  Those are two separate issues.  Running bad code can indeed damage your system, but it will do so regardless of whether you run it in the terminal or in an interactive interpreter.

Comment: The first question was if I could damage my system. So you answered that as possible. We can check that one off.

The second question was is it more convenient/efficient to run code interactively.

Comment: As long as you don't interact with the filesystem you probably won't run into problems. If you are just learning you can always use a sandboxed online interpreter like http://ideone.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you don't mess up with the system files, you might not do any damages. Be sure what files you might be disturbing. If your code is too, ummmm, core, try to give ideone.com a try. This might help you with the things you might b touching.

Terminal might not give you enough interactions, but as you told that you are new to coding, terminal is important. Get along with it. Find error without syntax highlighting feature. It will definitely help in the future. But yes, this is applicable if you are going for it seriously, gradually.

Comment: If I need to import packages for my program to run though I will have to create the .py file from an editor and then run the program inside Terminal correct?

Comment: You can create a Python module directly from the Python shell to import other built-in (or made by you) modules in your code and run that module directly in the shell.

    Though yes, everything (Virtually) in this world can be done from Terminal too.